# use mod_rewrite to change url prefixes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change many urls on a site with static html pages so that they're more descriptive. There are too many pages to use a simple redirect for each page. The actual page content will only change slowly over time as products change.

The site host permits access to the .htaccess within the same ftp folder as the site content, though I cannot edit the .htaccess in the folder above that.

Typical examples:

I want all urls beginning "estuc2_" to redirect to "expositores-"

e.g. /estuc2_4.html becomes /expositores-4.html

OR urls beginning "bolsa3_" to redirect to "bolsas-papel-con-asa-3"

e.g. /bolsa3_1.html becomes /bolsas-papel-con-asa-3.html

Have read reams of stuff on the net about htaccess, mod_rewrite, redirect etc but I cannot make this work and would be v grateful for some code. Also, it's not clear to me whether I should precede the strings with "/".

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. On my local MAMP working environment I had to add the complete localhost url to the new destination address, but on the host's server it works with just the forward slash, as you have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^estuc2_(.*)$ /expositores-$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^bolsa3_(.*)$ /bolsas-papel-con-asa-3$1 [L,R=301]
```

As far as:

> Also, it's not clear to me whether I should precede the strings with "/".

When you use mod_rewrite rules inside an htaccess file or a `<Directory>` container, the leading slash is stripped off so you can't match against it.